# 310 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error after enabling ssl certificate in nopcommerce

Tags: redirects, https, http, error

After I installed and turned on a SSL certificate, I began to receive 310 errors. The site is built with nopcommerce.

SSL Settings on the site are all included:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?  That can sometimes fix this type of problem.

Comment: I'd clear the browser cache, or switch to a different browser to test. I've encountered these issues many times and a forced refresh usually solves it. I went to the site and I don't get the error you are getting. I would also suggest forcing https, which you are not doing right now.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus , Now redirect disabled. The error appears when the redirection is enabled

Comment: @WebMorda In other words, there is some piece of code that's adding a resource with http:// instead of https://.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding a line to the file `WebConfig`

`<add key="Use_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="true" />`